# Allow job search to include both local *and* telecommute opportunities

Tags: feature-request, jobs

If I want a job which is *either* work from home *or* telecommute I need to do two searches. I think it makes more sense to have the "Work Remotely" button function as a checkbox to include remote positions if checked and not include them if not checked. In such a case, I would make it so that the leftmost position of the distance slider represented telecommute only.

Comment: What about the case of people who're only searching for remote positions?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards If I were to author the change, I would make the leftmost point on the distance slider represent telecommute only (which makes sense: a radius of 0 can only include where one is). I'd also argue that "slider @ 0 == no radius" is more consistent than "slider @ 0 == 20 miles".